# curl OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection was reset error

Tags: curl, openssl, https

I am trying to run below command from azure VM. i am getting error. I have also validated the port connectivity and 443 is open for status.cloud.google.com. Is there anything else i am missing. please suggest.

```
curl -vk https://status.cloud.google.com
*   Trying 142.250.101.100:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to status.cloud.google.com (142.250.101.100) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/certname.pem
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to status.cloud.google.com:443
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to status.cloud.google.com:443
```

Comment: Could be something wrong with the distro you're using. It works just fine here on Fedora 36. After `* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):` I get `* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):` `* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):`  instead.

Comment: Not Sure. Could it be a firewall level issue. Some document says even though the port is open, SSL traffic gets blocked.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73496312/how-to-fix-curl-error-openssl-ssl-connect-connection-reset-by-peer-in-connect/74312748#74312748